# How to find the given value from the range of values?

Tags: r

```
I have have the below data :

Y          z
100-800    a
150-600    b
200-300    c
400-600    d
4000-12000 e
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Based on given value of x (i.e x=100) it should find the values in the given ranges of Y and give the corresponding values of Y and z.If the given of x is not in the given ranges of Y then it should find the nearer range and give corresponding values of Y and Z.

DT[, list(OK = 1 %in% seq(Y, Y)), by = Z]

For given value of X=110

output should be

```
Y          Z
100-800    a

For x=200

Y          z
100-800    a
150-600    b
200-300    c

For x=12500

Y             z
4000-12000    e
```

Comment: That might be hard. Are there other values(not intervals) in the data? Might use some regex which might be less efficient.

Comment: Let say If I separate Y to Y1 and Y2 .Then can we solve this ?

Comment: Yes, separating might be an easier approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a helper function using `tidyr::separate` to separate columns. In case if there are no indices which fall within the range we compare the `value` with lowest value and highest value in the dataframe and return the row accordingly.

```
subset_fun <- function(df, val) {
   df1 <- tidyr::separate(df, Y, c("low", "high"), sep = "-",convert = TRUE)
   inds <- with(df1, val >= low & val <= high)
   if (any(inds))
      df[inds, ]
   else if (min(df1$low) > val) df[which.min(df1$low), ] 
        else df[which.max(df1$high), ] 
}

subset_fun(df, 100)
#        Y z
#1 100-800 a

subset_fun(df, 200)
#        Y z
#1 100-800 a
#2 150-600 b
#3 200-300 c

subset_fun(df, 12500)
#           Y z
#5 4000-12000 e

subset_fun(df, 0)
#        Y z
#1 100-800 a
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Y = structure(1:5, .Label = c("100-800", "150-600", 
"200-300", "400-600", "4000-12000"), class = "factor"), 
z = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a helper and use this to subset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
find_number <- function(x,high,low){
  x >= low & x < high # might be able to use between
}
     df %>% 
  separate(Y,c("Low","High")) -> new_df
 new_df[new_df %>% 
  mutate(Logi=find_number(200,high = High,low=Low)) %>% 
   pull("Logi"),]
  Low High z
1 100  800 a
2 150  600 b
3 200  300 c
```

**EDIT**: An attempt to automate this process. Using NSE might be a much better option since that would eliminate the need to have the exact same names as in this answer. In other words, redefine the function with a data and column name arguments. For now:

```
find_number <- function(x){

new_df[new_df %>% 
         mutate(Logi=x >= Low & x< High,
                isMax=ifelse(High==max(High) 
                             & x>High,
                             TRUE,Logi)) %>% 
    pull("isMax"),]


}

  find_number(12500)
   Low  High z
 5 4000 12000 e
```

Data:

```
new_df<-structure(list(Low = c(100, 150, 200, 400, 4000), High = c(800, 
600, 300, 600, 12000), z = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: OK, maybe it should be automated.

Comment: can we automate this for any given value of x ? That is I have one column of having all the values of X .Need to match will the other table df.

Comment: Sorry, why should 12500 fall between 4000 and 12000?

Comment: As that is only range which is near to 12500.

Comment: rather than hardcoding with 200, can we make it dynamic?

Comment: I'm still trying to write up a general solution that I will update.